# Did someone took birth in bayt ul mamur?

Tags: hadith, sunni, shiism, kaabah, qiblah

Shia believe Ali bin abi Talib was born inside Kaaba.

My question is does someone have birthplace as bayt ul mamur?

Bayt ul mamur is kaabah/qiblah of heavenly creatures located on highest heaven. 70000 (seventy thousand) Angels pray here and donot return.

Secondly, Is bayt ul mamur present in Shia literature?

Comment: Please check the site prior to asking questions that already are answered question [Was hazrat Aki ra born inside the Kaaba](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/was-hazrat-ali-ra-born-inside-the-kabba-with-the-walls-cracked)

Comment: Bayt ul mamur is kaaba on seventh heaven

Comment: How can somebody be born in  place that can't be reached -alive- except for chosen people?

Comment: Why shouldn't al-Bayt al-Ma'amoor be present in Shi'a literature when it is in the qur'an 
 in surat at-Tur "And [by] the frequented House" [52:4](https://legacy.quran.com/52/4)

Answer (score 0):

Beit al-Ma'mour is a house in the fourth or seventh heaven, the sanctuary (equal to or opposite to) the house of the Ka'bah where the angels are always engaged in worship and Tawaf. This combination was first used in the Holy Quran and then in Islamic traditions. Therefore, Beit Al-Ma'mour is not the Kaaba, but is equal to or above the Kaaba in another world. And it is not on earth at all until someone was born in it.

As for the answer to your second question, I must say that in Persian literature, religious concepts and terms have had a significant presence. I have not had much. But the famous ancient poets of Iran according to the official religion at that time were mostly Sunnis and those who were Shiites hid their religion due to piety. And if it became clear that they were Shiites, not only their works and writings, but also their person would be in danger. Therefore, the works of literature of the past cannot be clearly distinguished in terms of being Shiite and Sunni.

**Source**:

- https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa98867
- https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A8%DB%8C%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B1